# Best way to receive C++ uint8_t* buffer on Rust

Tags: rust

Suppose I have a C++ allocated buffer `uint8_t*` and I want to access it from Rust:

One way would be to have the C++ function:

```
uint8_t receive(uint8_t** data, size_t* size) {
    //allocates the data, writes to it and then points *data to it
    return 0;//on success
}
```

however this leaves Rust responsible for dealocating the data. Same for

```
uint8_t* receive(size_t* size) {
    uit8_t* data = //allocates data
    *size = data_size;
    return data;
}
```

The idea I have is to allocate the data on Rust and then pass a pointer for C++ to fill:

```
uint8_t receive(uint8_t* data, size_t size) {
    //fills data up to size
    return 0;
}
```

However, we cannot simply allocate a buffer in Rust and expect it to be C/C++ compatible. Also it has the limitation of having to know a size in advance, or use a sufficiently big size for all buffers.

What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: "However, we cannot simply allocate a buffer in Rust and expect it to be C/C++ compatible." sure you can, a buffer is just a valid pointer to a bunch of bytes, that's really rather innocuous.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you're going to need to allocate memory and free memory in the same language.  It isn't guaranteed that C or C++ and Rust will use the same allocator.  For example, on Windows, different shared libraries can use different allocators and therefore memory allocated by one shared library cannot necessarily be freed by another.  Rust can also use custom allocators that need not match the system allocator.

One way to do this would be to have your `receive` function call an `extern "C"` Rust function to allocate or deallocate the memory you want in a suitable size.

If you do want to allocate this in Rust, you can create a `Vec<u8>` using `Vec::with_capacity`, then use the nightly API, `Vec::into_raw_parts` to turn it into a pointer, size, and capacity, and then destroy it later by doing `Vec::from_raw_parts` and dropping the object, which will free it.  That does assume that data layout in Rust is the same as C++, but for chunks of consecutive memory with built-in types, this is probably a safe assumption since Rust will practically need to follow the system ABI.

Of course, since all of this uses pointers, it is necessarily `unsafe`.

You might also find that your `receive` function could be just as well written in Rust as an `extern "C"` function, which might meet your needs better.  Without knowing more about your use case, it's hard to say.